# Drupal 7.x DOCTYPE Issue

Tags: drupal-7

my website seems to have an issue when viewed in IE (I am currently using IE10) with compatibility view turned on. I have noticed 2 of my pages have the text and images pushed to the right of the form (looks like it is right-aligned) but shouldn't be. I have a html.tpl.php page (located in the modules/system directory) that has the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>"           version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>
```

When compatibility view is turned off, the webpage is correct. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!